# Error when opening class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am new to visual studio 2013 vb.net
I am getting this error message when I open any class in my project.
Can anyone explain what this means and maybe a possible fix?
Thanks!

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>   No exports were found that match the constraint:
>           -------------ContractName
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
>           -------------RequiredTypeIdentity
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.IContentTypeRegistryService
>
> ---

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall VS?

Comment: No I updated the Server Explorer to 2014

Comment: Thanks I had to reinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall Visual Studio. Keep the projects and start fresh.